# Whenever I try to use rangeOfString it says member not found in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var text: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      let boldRange = text.rangeOfString(NSLocalizedString("bold", comment: ""))
        // issue is here. 
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Whenever using `rangeOfString` I run into this issue but I am not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `text` property of the text view:

```
let boldRange = text.text.rangeOfString(NSLocalizedString("bold", comment: ""))
```